# Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the plane described by $x + 2y + 3z = 0$ in $R^3$. Let $\vec{c}$ = {1,2,3}, which
is the vector perpendicular to this plane. The goal is to find a matrix that performs reflection across this plane.

(a) Find a basis {$\vec{a}$,$\vec{b}$} for the vectors on the plane.

(b) Show that $B$ = {$\vec{a}$,$\vec{b}$,$\vec{c}$} is a basis for $R^3$.

(c) The transformation $T$ : $R^3$ → $R^3$ which reflects vectors across the plane should map $\vec{a}$ → $\vec{a}$,$\vec{b}$→ $\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$→ -$\vec{c}$. Knowing this, find the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$. (Namely, find $[T]_B$.)

(d) Find the matrix $A$ of $T$ with respect to the standard basis.

I could use some help setting this one up. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For (a), find two linearly independent vectors (x,y,z) satisfying your plane equation.  Once you have that the rest should be straightforward, as long as you know the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: start with $\bar a= \left (\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ -1 \\0 \end{array} \right )$ and $\bar b=\left (\begin{array}{c} 3 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{array} \right )$ and show $det(\bar a,\bar b,\bar c) \neq 0$.